# React function components naming issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When my component name is **WithErrorHandler** I get the following error:

> React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

But when I change it to **withErrorHandler** it works fine. (first letter is lower cased)

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong here?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal';
import WrapperComponent from '../WrapperComponent/WrapperComponent';

const WithErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
    return props => {
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);

        const reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
            setError(null);
            return req;
        });

        const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(res => res, error => {
            setError(error);
        });

        useEffect(() => {
            return () => {
                axios.interceptors.request.eject(reqInterceptor);
                axios.interceptors.response.eject(resInterceptor);
            };
        }, [reqInterceptor, resInterceptor]);

        const closeModalHandler = () => setError(null);

        return (
            <WrapperComponent>
                <Modal show={error} hide={closeModalHandler}>
                    {error ? error.message : null}
                </Modal>
                <WrappedComponent {...props} />
            </WrapperComponent>
        )
    }
}

export default WithErrorHandler;
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what's going on here but components in React must be capitalized

Comment: @Redseb it's not _a_ component, it's a Higher-Order Component, which is just a function returning a new component and it's name is irrelevant, though the tools can misinterpret the function as a component and throw the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's tripping the safeguard about hooks even though it's still valid code.

Just name it `withErrorHandler` as it's not a component, it's a function returning a component, known as an [Higher-Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

You could also give a name to the returned component.

```
// Use camelCase for the HOC function.
const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {

    // Use PascalCase for the name of the component itself (optional but encouraged).
    return function WithErrorHandler(props) => {

        // This hook is at the right place already!
        const [error, setError] = useState(null);

        // ...

        return /*...*/
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler;
```